# What is causing my NotifyIcon to hide after Alt+F4?

Tags: c#, wpf, notifications, system-tray

I have A WPF app using a winforms `NotifyIcon` for showing a context menu on the tray. When I perform the following steps the icon disappears.

1. Right click on the notify icon in the tray
2. Select a context menu item that displays a modal dialog
3. Dismiss that dialog
4. Press Alt+F4

Here is a minimal example where I see this bug.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="killtrayicon.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:killtrayicon"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button Content="button" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
namespace killtrayicon
{
    using System.Windows;

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon notifyIcon = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            notifyIcon.Icon = Properties.Resources.icon;
            notifyIcon.Visible = true;
            notifyIcon.Text = "test";
            notifyIcon.ContextMenu = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu();
            notifyIcon.ContextMenu.MenuItems.Add("click", (s, e) =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("menu");
            });
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            notifyIcon.Icon = Properties.Resources.icon;
        }
    }
}
```

Clicking the button in my main window resets the icon and the notify icon appears again. So the notify icon itself has not been removed. Inspecting the instance of `NotifyIcon` shows it is still visible before resetting the icon and the `Icon` property is pointing to a valid ICO in my resources.

I suspect that the context menu is the issue because if I show a modal dialog via clicking on the tray icon, this issue doesn't occur.

How do I get the NotifyIcon to not respond to Alt+F4?

Edit: This question is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063480/disabling-alt-f4-on-a-win-forms-notifyicon) but that question has no sample code to reproduce the issue (dead link), the link to the issue submitted to Microsoft is also a dead link, and there's no accepted answer with an actual solution.

Comment: Wow a downvote for a better worded question with no dead links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered the solution. The `NotifyIcon` creates a hidden `NativeWindow` as a recipient for window messages generated by the icon created by `Shell_NotifyIcon`. That window is using the default window proc which handles `Alt+F4` like any other window. By turning it into `WM_CLOSE`. You need to use Win32 API's to subclass the `HWND` in that `NativeWindow`, intercept that `WM_CLOSE`, and ignore it.

First add some Win32 methods from comctl32.dll:

```
public static class Comctl32
{
    public const string DLL = "comctl32.dll";

    public const uint WM_CLOSE = 0x0010;
    public const uint WM_NCDESTROY = 0x0082;

    public delegate IntPtr SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint uMsg, UIntPtr wParam, UIntPtr lParam, UIntPtr uIdSubclass, UIntPtr dwRefData);

    [DllImport(DLL, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool SetWindowSubclass(
        [param: In]
            IntPtr hWnd,
        [param: In]
            SubclassWndProc pfnSubclass,
        [param: In]
            UIntPtr uIdSubclass,
        [param: In]
            UIntPtr dwRefData);

    [DllImport(DLL, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool RemoveWindowSubclass(
        [param: In]
            IntPtr hWnd,
        [param: In]
            SubclassWndProc pfnSubclass,
        [param: In]
            UIntPtr uIdSubclass);

    [DllImport(DLL, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern IntPtr DefSubclassProc(
        [param: In]
            IntPtr hWnd,
        [param: In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
            uint uMsg,
        [param: In]
            UIntPtr WPARAM,
        [param: In]
            UIntPtr LPARAM);
}
```

Then add code to your `NotifyIcon` to subclass the hidden tray icon window. You'll need to use reflection to get at the window because it's not public:

```
private Native.Comctl32.SubclassWndProc subclassWndProc;

...

// Get the HWND from the notify icon
Type notifyIconType = typeof(System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon);
BindingFlags hidden = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
var window = notifyIconType.GetField("window", hidden).GetValue(this.notifyIcon) as System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow;

// Inject our window proc to intercept window messages
this.subclassWndProc = this.TrayWndProc;
Native.Comctl32.SetWindowSubclass(window.Handle, this.subclassWndProc, UIntPtr.Zero, UIntPtr.Zero);
```

Then intercept the `WM_CLOSE` to ignore `Alt+F4`. We also make sure to un-subclass on `WM_NCDESTROY`:

```
private IntPtr TrayWndProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint uMsg, UIntPtr wParam, UIntPtr lParam, UIntPtr uIdSubclass, UIntPtr dwRefData)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        // Ignore the close message to avoid Alt+F4 killing the tray icon
        case Native.Comctl32.WM_CLOSE:
            return IntPtr.Zero;

        // Clean up subclassing
        case Native.Comctl32.WM_NCDESTROY:
            Native.Comctl32.RemoveWindowSubclass(hWnd, this.subclassWndProc, UIntPtr.Zero))
            break;
    }

    // Invoke the default window proc
    return Native.Comctl32.DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```